# Delete words which have 2 consecutive vowels in it

Tags: python, performance, algorithm

What i want is remove the words which have more than two consecutive vowels in it. So input:

```
s = " There was a boat in the rain near the shore, by some mysterious lake"
```

Output:

```
[boat,rain,near,mysterious]
```

So here is my code.
I was just wondering if there is any better way to do this or is this efficient enough.And if you can do this with python dict or lists are ok? :) I'm new to python so yeah. :) comments would be nice.

```
def change(s):
vowel = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
words = []
a = s[:].replace(",","").split()
for i in vowel:
    s = s.replace(i, "*").replace(",","")
for i,j in enumerate(s.split()):
    if "**" in j:
        words.append(a[i])
return words
```

Comment: "words which have more than two consecutive vowels" You mean words that have ***two or more*** consecutive vowels? Otherwise only `mysterious` counts.

Comment: For the curious, of the current solutions posted ajcr's wins (timewise) by a few microseconds. `re.search` comes in at ~21micros, Set intersection slicing comes in at ~60micros. Pairwise iteration comes in at ~35micros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using sets:

First method using [set.intersection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) will only find non identical consecutive pairs so `oo` would not be a match:

```
s = " There was a boat in the rain near the shore, by some mysterious lake"
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
print([x for x in s.split() if any(len(set(x[i:i+2]).intersection(vowels))==  2 for i in range(len(x))) ])
['boat', 'rain', 'near', 'mysterious']
```

Method 2 uses [set.issubset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) so now identical consecutive pairs will be considered a match.

using `set.issubset` with a function using the `yield from` python 3 syntax which might be more appropriate and indeed to catch repeated identical vowels :

```
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
def get(x, step):
    yield from (x[i:i+step] for i in range(len(x[:-1])))

print([x for x in s.split() if any(set(pr).issubset(vowels) for pr in get(x, 2))])
```

Or again in a single list comp:

```
print([x for x in s.split() if any(set(pr).issubset(vowels) for pr in (x[i:i+2] for i in range(len(x[:-1]))))])
```

Finally make vowels a set and check if it is a [set.issuperset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) of any pair of chars:

```
vowels = {'a', 'u', 'U', 'o', 'e', 'i', 'A', 'I', 'E', 'O'}


def get(x, step):
    yield from (x[i:i+step] for i in range(len(x[:-1])))

print([x for x in s.split() if any(vowels.issuperset(pr) for pr in get(x, 2))])
```

Comment: Set intersection using slices is a novel way to look at this question. I like it!

Comment: Here's a variant of your last example that doesn't need a helper function: `[x for x in s.split() if any(vowels.issuperset(pr) for pr in zip(x, x[1:]))]`

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you could always use regular expressions and list comprehension to get the list of words:

```
>>> import re
>>> [x for x in s.split() if re.search(r'[aeiou]{2}', x)]
['boat', 'rain', 'near', 'mysterious']
```

`s.split()` splits the sentence into a list of words. The expression `[x for x in s.split()]` considers each word in this list in turn.

The `re.search(r'[aeiou]{2}', x)` part of the expression searches each word for two consecutive letters from the group `[aeiou]`. Only if two consecutive vowels are found is the word put in the new list.

Comment: Don't forget the comma in your pattern, otherwise this will search for strictly two consecutive vowels rather than at least.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi `{2,}` is strictly a superset of `{2}`. You don't need the trailing comma.

Answer (score 3):

Using pairwise iteration:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iter(iterable))
    next(b)
    return zip(a,b)

vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
[word for word in s.split() if any(
        this in vowels and next in vowels for this,next in pairwise(word))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions instead:

```
import re

s = 'There was a boat in the rain near the shore, by some mysterious lake'
l = [i for i in s.split(' ') if re.search('[aeiou]{2,}', i)]

print ' '.join(l) # back to string
```

Comment: Couple big issues here. You're mutating the same list you're iterating on: `for word in l: ... l.remove(word)` is scary, use `for word in l[:]`; and `if not ... is None` -- just use `if re.search(r'[aeiou]{2}', word)`. Note also that you don't need the trailing comma in that quantifier, since you're just concerned with two in a row, and don't care if there are more.

Comment: Right in the question it says more. Secondly, the iteration is fine because I'm not iterating by index, I'm iterating with a foreach.

Comment: As I mentioned in the other answer, it's not possible to match `{2}` and not `{2,}`. Your regex should quit when it matches 2, there's no reason to keep matching more. I consider mutating the list you're iterating over a code smell. Just because it doesn't break this use case doesn't mean it's good code.

Answer (score 1):

Using product instead:

```
from itertools import product

vowels = 'aiueo'
comb = list(product(vowels, repeat=2))
s = " There was a boat in the rain near the shore, by some mysterious lake"


def is2consecutive_vowels(word):
    for i in range(len(word)-1):
        if (word[i], word[i+1]) in comb:
            return True
    return False

print [word for word in s.split() if is2consecutive_vowels(word)]
# ['boat', 'rain', 'near', 'mysterious']
```

or if you don't need to use any external library:

```
vowels = 'aeiou'

def is2consecutive_vowels2(word):
    for i in range(len(word)-1):
        if word[i] in vowels and word[i+1] in vowels:
            return True
    return False

print [word for word in s.split() if is2consecutive_vowels2(word)]
# ['boat', 'rain', 'near', 'mysterious']
```

This one is even quicker than regex solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
a=[]
def count(s):
    c=0
    t=s.split()
    for i in t:
        for j in range(len(i)-1):
            w=i[j]
            u=i[j+1]
            if u in "aeiou" and w in "aeiou":
                c+=1
        if(c>=1):
            a.append(i)
        c=0
    return(a)
print(count("There was a boat in the rain near the shore, by some mysterious lake"))
```